# ARM Assembly Multiplication Error

Tags: assembly, arm, multiplication

I'm having a problem trying to multiply two numbers and store them in a memory location in ARM assembly.  I'm simulating an ARM Cortex M0 Plus.  Everything seems to be working fine when I comment out the multiplication.  I'm not sure whether I need to use MUL or MULS but either way I don't see why it's not working.  The equation I'm trying to solve is:

```
A = 2
B = 4
C = 6
D = A+(C*B)-2
```

When I uncomment the multiplication the error I get is "Error: could not load file.  Debugger aborted!"  *Error was caused by registers in an incorrect order.  It's easier to add location first, then the registers used to multiply

Code:

```
    AREA |.text|, CODE, READONLY, ALIGN=2
    EXPORT __main

    ;equate x20000000 with some x
A   EQU 0x20000000
B   EQU 0x20000004
C   EQU 0x20000008
D   EQU 0x2000000C

__main
    ;A = 2
    MOVS R0, #2
    ;move pointer to =0x20000000
    LDR R7, =A
    ;Store R0 in memory cell of address R7
    STR R0, [R7]

    ;B = 4
    MOVS R0, #4
    LDR R7, =B
    STR R0, [R7]

    ;C = 6
    MOVS R0, #6
    LDR R7, =C
    STR R0, [R7]

    ;A+(C*B)-2
    LDR R7, =C
    LDR R0, [R7]
    LDR R7, =B
    LDR R1, [R7]
;   MUL R0, R1 ;C*B

;EDIT FIXED above line should be:
    MULS R0, R1, R0
;   This stores in location R0, multiplication R1, R0

    LDR R7, =A
    LDR R1, [R7]
    ADDS R0, R1 ;A+(C*B)
    SUBS R0, #2 ;(A+(C*B))-2

    ;D = R0
    LDR R7, =D ;storing result in D
    STR R0, [R7]

done
    B done
    END
```

Comment: That looks very much like a secondary error message, i.e. the debugger can't load the file which doesn't exist because the assembler errored out creating it. I'm guessing you're using an IDE - somewhere it should have some sort of build log to let you see what the assembler itself had to say. Whichever way, consulting [the specific instruction set documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0662b/BABJJACB.html) would be worthwhile. I don't see how this would do what you want anyway, given that you immediately trash the result of the multiplication with the load...

Comment: 1. `A+(D*C)-2` is not an equation you can solve, because there is no `=` sign and no unknowns. 2. Why not pre-compile it? If everything is constant, just use assembly defined constants and write `LDR Rx, =A+(D*C)-2` that should work.

Comment: @Notlikethat Yeah, it's an error message.  I'm using uVision but I can't figure out how to get more information on the errors.  I'm using the free version and that might be why.  It's an online class which is kind of hard to follow because there are no discussions.  I've been reading the documentation, but without knowing exactly how it all fits makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: @Bregalad Sorry, I wrote it in incorrectly.  'D' is supposed to equal "A+(C*B)-2

I was avoiding B because it's showing up in blue, but I'm going to try to use it and if I can't I'll switch back to incrementing one letter past 'B'

Comment: Now your equation reduces to `D = D*6` (by substituing A and C) and the answer is `D=0`. This is a math problem, not a computer one :)

Comment: @Notlikethat You mean that I have to store the result outside of the register even if I'm going to use that same register in the next expression?    When I try that, I get the same result: an error message.

Comment: @Bregalad Haha, I'm off it today.  It's A + C * B - 2 or
 D = A + (C*B) - 2  Also, I know it reduces to 24, but I'm pretty sure the professor wants me to do the problem.

Comment: No, more that you need to get your source and destination operands the right way round. MUL (and variants) is the weirdo in that respect ;) Off-topic, one thing I would suggest to make the code easier to manage is load r7 with the base pointer only once, then use offset addressing to access the individual variables, e.g. `str r0, [r7, #4]` to store B.

Comment: OK so now that the problem to solve is clear, you should add the error message you're getting in the question. To me it looks like your code is perfectly ok (except when you do  `LDR R7, =D` where it's supposed ot be `C`, but that shouldn't be a compile error). Normally if you do `mul A, B` the assembler automatically adds the operand in the correct order so that `A := A*B` so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks, it's working fine now.  I had to make sure to add the location first for it to work even though the documentation says it's optional, but it's working.

Comment: @Bregalad Done, thanks.  I had to switch the order for it to work correctly.  I'm assuming the order that I used originally had stored the C*B in register R1

Comment: Oh so the problem was your assembler not supporting the 2-operand `mul` pseudo-instruction? Man that's strange. Anyway, glad it's fixed :)

Comment: By the way, `muls` will affect the status flags, while `mul` will preserve them. That's the only difference. Since you're not using them, it makes no difference which one you use, but for some reason the convension is to not affect status flags if you don't need them (so that when you see an instruciton with `-s` ending, it makes it clear you are interested in it's status flags).

Comment: @Bregalad I'll keep that in mind.  In this case though, the ARM Cortex M0 Plus doesn't allow me to use MUL instead of MULS